# after_create trigger just if is called from rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Hi I have a custom after_create action in my model, but I just want to trigger it if the object was created from Rails_admin, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Add a virtual attribute to the model, set its value in the controller based on some attribute sent via Rails_admin or whether the current_user is an admin, then check for it in your custom callback.  For example, if your model is a User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :is_admin #Virtual Attribute
  after_create :my_custom_callback

  
  def my_custom_callback
    unless self.is_admin.blank?
      #Handle callback logic
    end
  end
end
```

Add a param to the data coming from Rails_admin. You can skip this if you have some type of 'admin' role on the current user.

Then in your controller that handles the creation of the object, set the is_admin attribute on your model instance like:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(blah blah blah)
    unless params[:rails_admin].blank? # Ideally current_user.admin would be better
      @user.is_admin = true
    end
    @user.save
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom callback something like,

```
class Admin < ApplicationRecord
  
  after_create :custom_callback
  
  def custom_callback
    if self.user_type == "ADMIN"
      # Add rails admin login here
    end
  end
end

# Call this from controller

def create_admin
  Admin.create!(user_type: "ADMIN", other_details: "")
end

> if can manage user_type column in DB then you can directly call using self otherwise you can add attr_reader in you model like,
attr_reader :user_type
More about on attr_reader refer this [1]

  [1]: https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_reader
```